# Calling object from mainform.cs in other forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, namespaces

i want to call anything from mainform (mainform.cs) from GraficDisplay (namespace) 
in the other (namespace) : GraphLib , but i can't , would any one tell me why? and how can i resolve this problem? Its been giving me hard time since the start of the project, every time I try these errors appear:

When I call:

```
mainform.toolstriplabel1.text = "87";
```

this appears:

> The name 'mainform' does not exist in the current context

and if I call this:

```
GraficDisplay.MainForm.toolstriplabel1.text = "87";
```

this appears:

> The name 'GraficDisplay' does not exist in the current context

I mean I even can't call the `GraficDisplay` (namespace) in GraphLib (namespace)
also the `MainForm` is `public` and `partial`.

Comment: Are those two namespaces in different assemblies? If so, did you add them as references?

Comment: I'm assuming `mainform` isn't a property of whatever your trying to call it from.. Why do you need to though? you are opening up to a world of debugging pain. and a namespace holds no space in memory (Afaik its "lost" in compilation?)

Comment: well don't mock me but i haven't learned this far , and i'v been given this project to do , it's prewritten , i'm just somehow tweaking it for someone , and since not every one knows C# , i have to do it , this is the solution title: Solution 'GraficDisplay (2Projects)'

Comment: well MainForm is a Class , and i have to , there is a text box that when it's text is changed , the graph titles should change , this is in another form in GraphLib (namespace) , so i have to either call the toolstriplabel and display.DataSources[].Name From MainForm in GraphLib or the textchange property from GraphLib in MainForm , i cant' do neither of them

Comment: @nvoigt since it is prewritten i dont' know, how should i solve it? here is the link for the program : http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/GraphPlotting/GraphDisplaySrc_12072009.zip

Comment: So what it sounds to me that you should be doing is when the `TextChanged` (cant remember the exact event name but its something like this) event is triggered on that textbox, you should be telling your program to send a method to the other form with a string containing the new text. Your form will need to know about the other form though.

Comment: yes exactly , and that expands the problem , i cant use the term "using" , because when i do it also generates error, the same as above

Comment: Somehow there will be (should be) a link between your forms since they were formed from the same program, find this link.

Comment: how should i find that?? i haven't learned much , have just started university last year , so we weren't taught this much , if any one could help i'd be grateful, i have provided the link , it's safe and it's just abou 250 KBs , so any one needed it can download it , thanx guys

Comment: Sorry I don't click on any links on stack overflow other than to other stack overflow questions and msdn..You need to find where the graph form is opened, I presume since it is called `mainform.cs` that it is the first form that is opened so I'd imagine at some point, that form opens up the others

Comment: yeah , it opens from another supposedly form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually don't follow links here either but CodeProject is a rather reliable source imo, so I had a look.

**Edit**: I was confused as to what you want. Here is what you seem to actually wnat:

The problem is about referencing a form or part of it from another form or part of it. It is further a problem of dealing with a Library, that really shouldn't be messed up be adding namespaces of an example application or dependencies etc..

So what you want is **loose coupling**.

Here is a solution that uses references in the library objects and register methods to fill the references. If you don't register anything the library will work normally.

This solution can be changed and expanded but I'll leave it at registering two objects: One is a Control, eg.g a TextBox; the other is a Component e.g. a ToolStripItem. If you want to reference only the ToolStripItem you can omit the references to the Control and the RegisterCtl methods.

In hat case you can and should also substitute 'Component' for 'ToolStripItem' to make things thighter!

First you go to the ultimate consumer of the actions, `PlotterGraphSelectCurvesForm`. Here you add these two blocks of code:

```
public partial class PlotterGraphSelectCurvesForm : Form
{
    private int selectetGraphIndex = -1;
    private PlotterGraphPaneEx gpane = null;

    // block one: a Control reference (if you like!):
    Control myTextCtl;
    public void RegisterCtl(Control ctl) { if (ctl != null) myTextCtl = ctl; }

    // block one: a Component reference:
    Component myTextComp;
    public void RegisterComp(Component comp) { if (comp != null)  myTextComp = comp; }  
    //..
```

Next you code what you want to happen, maybe like this:

```
    void tb_GraphName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (selectetGraphIndex >= 0 && selectetGraphIndex < gpane.Sources.Count)
        {
            DataSource src = gpane.Sources[selectetGraphIndex];
            String Text = tb_GraphName.Text;

            // all controls have a Text:
            if (myTextCtl != null) myTextCtl.Text = Text;
            // here you need to know the type:
            if (myTextComp != null) ((ToolStripItem) myTextComp).Text = Text;
            //..   

        }
```

In theory all you now need to do is to register the TextBox and/or the ToolStripItem in the Mainform.. However, there is a complication: The `PlotterGraphSelectCurvesForm` is not called from the `Mainform`! Instead it is called from a `UserObject PlotterGraphPaneEx`, which in turn is sitting in the MainForm. In the same sprit of not messing up the library by creating dependencies you simply add the very same references and registration methods to this UO as well:

```
public partial class PlotterDisplayEx : UserControl
{         
    #region MEMBERS

    Control myTextCtl;
    public void RegisterCtl(Control ctl) { if (ctl != null) myTextCtl = ctl; }

    Component myTextComp;
    public void RegisterComp(Component comp) { if (comp != null) myTextComp = comp; } 
    //..
```

Now you can actually register things, both in the MainForm..:

```
    public MainForm()
    {           
        InitializeComponent();

        display.RegisterCtl(aDemoTextBox);
        display.RegisterComp(toolstriplabel1);
        //..
```

..and in the UO:

```
    private void selectGraphsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (GraphPropertiesForm == null)
        {
            GraphPropertiesForm = new PlotterGraphSelectCurvesForm();
            GraphPropertiesForm.RegisterCtl(myTextCtl);
            GraphPropertiesForm.RegisterComp(myTextComp);
        }
    //..
```

Now when you open the Properties form and change the LabelText you can see both the text in the Graphs and the text in both the Menu and the TextBox change..

Comment: well thanks , yeah i created the toolstriplabel1, it doesnt exist , if you look close ther is a form named "PlotterGraphPropertiesForm.cs" in the GraphLib namespace , there in the designer view you see the text box named : "tb_GraphName"   the program automatically updates the graph name when this text box's text is changed , now i want to add the capability of also automatically changing toolstriplabel1.text from the MainForm (from GraficDisplay Namespace)  , is there any way?? since the program doesn't let me add a reference from GraphLib to GraficDisplay , i used interface , but it also

Comment: fails because these are not defined to be overloaded tb_GraphName.TextChanged += new EventHandler(tb_GraphName_TextChanged);                                   public void tb_GraphName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) to this public void tb_GraphName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e, Access.Access ac)   ... (access is a namespace i created with a interface named access in it)

Comment: but on the other hand i tried to find wich code defines where these graph names are placed?? i tried the layout part but i couldn't find , i want to change the stacked modes name s to appear vertically by the left side , this the code defining the name :  display.DataSources[j].Name = "Graph " + (j + 1); line567 column66 character66

Comment: OK, lets get this straight. You have added a toolstrip to the mainmenu and want to reference it from where? From the PlotterGraphSelectCurvesForm popup window? Is that right?

Comment: yeah , well thanks so much , it's good to see someone actually cares about programming when others just rate the questions down , i hope this works , welldone , and thanks again

Comment: If you are happy with the solution you may want to accept the answer.

Comment: hey , so you saw this program , can you help me with the graphs?? i wanted to know that how can i make one of them be drawn dotted , other one dashed and so on , can u help me?

Comment: Sorry but I can't rewrite that program, you'll have to dig into it yourself. The first steps are to add a `System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle` property to the `PlotterGraphPaneEx`, to apply it to the pen: `p.DashStyle = lineStyle;` (Line ~845) and to add a combobox with the styles to the PropertiesForm. Its selectionchanged would then set the DashStyle property. I don't have time to look deeper into it to be sure how to make those settings stick. The GraphColors don't seem to stick either, so the programm may need some more work to do. It is just a demo after all..

Comment: well don't hate me man , i figured the dashing thing already , but i have another problem , on of the classes contained a public enum, i needed two more so i created , now the first one i created works well, but when i use my second one errors appear although both of thes are completely similar

Comment: well it was stupid , actually it was VisualStudios fault , solved anyway , i had to write the code above the previous enum to take effect whenever i added it under the previous one it would generate errors (ther wasn't any scopes so like i said VS's fault) and sorry , igot banned from asking questions :( thats why i can just comment

Comment: hii, sorry for bothering you , i had one final question , the most important one because i know there is no way i can do this on my own, i have to edit the xlabel so it shows costume times, but i don't know the default programs timer works based on second or not , so can you guide me how to understand that? and how can i edit this so the graph would be actually based on rate/time